# Calculate the limit of a sequence $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{I_{n}}{n^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Calculate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{n}}\int_{0}^{n}x^n\arctan(\sqrt[n]{x})dx$$

**My approach:** I was trying to solve first the integral, so for example for $n=1$, we have that
$$\int x\arctan(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}x^{2}\arctan(x)-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x)+c$$
and for $n=2$, we can see that $$\int x\arctan(\sqrt{x})dx=\frac{1}{6}(3(x^{2}-1)\arctan(\sqrt{x})-(x-3)\sqrt{x}+c$$
and for $n=3$, we have
$$\int x\arctan(\sqrt[3]{x})dx=\frac{1}{30}(-3x^{5/3}+15(x^{2}+1)\arctan(\sqrt[3]{x})+5x-15\sqrt[3]{x})+c$$

---

I was trying to see if by induction I could give a closed formula for the integral but the calculation of the integral does not show any pattern. How can I solve this limit?

Comment: Do you know Dominated Convergence Theorem ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Yes, I know  DCT, how can I use the DCT here?

Comment: So, the problem it boils down to calculating $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\lim_{n\to \infty} nu^{n}\arctan(\sqrt[n]{nu})du$? by DCT I can put the limit inside the integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $x = n - u$ to rewrite

$$ \frac{1}{n^n} \int_{0}^{n} x^n \arctan(x^{1/n}) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \left(1 - \frac{u}{n}\right)^n \arctan((n-u)^{1/n}) \mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(u) \, \mathrm{d}u. $$

Now by the dominated convergence theorem, this converges to

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1 - \frac{u}{n}\right)^n \arctan((n-u)^{1/n}) \mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(u) \, \mathrm{d}u
= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-u} \arctan(1) \, \mathrm{d}u
= \frac{\pi}{4}. $$

Comment: Nice solution, but can I guarantee that I can actually use the DCT on this problem?

Comment: @АлександрПальма It is useful to know that $$ \left(1-\frac{u}{n}\right)^n \leq e^{-u} $$ for all $u \leq n$. This follows from a more elementary inequality $1+t\leq e^t$ which holds for all real $t$. Now substitute $t=-u/n$ and raise both sides to the power of $n$. Then the integrand is bounded by $e^{-u}\arctan(\infty)=\frac{\pi}{2}e^{-u}$, which is integrable.

Comment: Oh, you're right! I didn't see that. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

$u = \frac{x}{n}$ gives you a simpler formula :
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_{0}^{1}n u^n\arctan(\sqrt[n]{nu})du$$

Comment: Yes, that is an interesting approach. But how is that integral solved?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use $t = \left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n+1}$

$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{n}\int_0^1 \tan^{-1}\left(n^{\frac{1}{n}}t^{\frac{1}{n^2+n}}\right)dt \to \int_0^1 \tan^{-1}(1)dt = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

by dominated convergence since the sequence is dominated by $g(t)=\pi$.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you so much :-)